# Calling a JS function from iterated objects on pageload

Tags: javascript, django, iteration, pageload

Good evening, I want to set my progressbars dynamically through Javascript by replacing the width value to the calculated percentage. I am running Django with a Postgres DB. Now I can set the styling just fine through a JS function but how would I have the function trigger at pageload?

Through the view I can pass the relevant number of votes for the iterated object (poll_product) and the total nr of votes. Those two I'd like to pass to my JS function as arguments, so I can calculate the percentage there and set it.

I hope I explained it clearly enough, but please ask away for anything I need to elaborate on.

```
            {% for poll_product in poll_product_list %}
                <form action="{% url 'add_vote' poll_product.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row mt-1">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <h5>{{ poll_product.product_type }} : {{ poll_product.votes }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            {% if user.is_authenticated and not voted %}
                                <input type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-dark" value="Vote">
                            {% endif%}
                        </div>
/* ------------ below is the relevant part ---------------- */
                        <div class="col-6 progress">
                            <div id="{{poll_product.id}}" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div>
                            <script>setProgressBar('{{poll_product.votes}}', '{{total_votes}}', '{{poll_product.id}}');</script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="{{ request.path }}">
                </form>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: maybe have a look at event listeners for on a page loading - like found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Thanks for answering Wally, I read that one and quite some others, but none explain how I would activate that and pass the arguments from each iterated object/element

Comment: You want to select all the progress bar elements, calculate the width and set the style whenever the page loads?

Comment: Hey Emiel, more or less, I want to calculate a percentage for each progressbar. The number of votes are supplied by the view (poll_product.votes). Based on that I want each progressbar to display the relevant percentage.

In the meantime I am able to pass the votes and total to my function like this:
 `<script>setProgressBar('{{poll_product.votes}}', '{{total_votes}}');</script>` (directly after the progressbar div)
Only thing is I need to load my external script in the beginning of the page now.

Answer (score 0):

Got this solved by calling this function:

```
function setProgressBar(productVotes, totalVotes, productID) {
    progressPercentage = Math.round(productVotes/totalVotes * 100);
    document.getElementById(productID).style.width = progressPercentage+"%";
}
```

Edited the code in the OP for the function call within HTML